# Reading binary data in a webapplication gets corrupted files

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, postgresql-9.1

I'm storing binary files/attachments in a Postgress database using an uploadpagein an ASP.Net MVC-webapplication. If I fetch these attachments in a console-program and write the contents to disk, all attachments are just fine and I can read all off them. If I execute exact the same code in my Webapp, the content gets of each attachment is corrupted. What is causing this ?

This is the code I'm using :

```
    private void DumpBijlagen( )
    {
        NpgsqlConnection connection = null;

        try
        {
            DataSet     ds              = new DataSet();
            DataTable   dt              = new DataTable();
            string  connectionString    = "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=gtsys;Password=gtsys;Database=postgis20";
            connection = new NpgsqlConnection( connectionString);

            StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder( );
            sb.AppendFormat( "select id, filename, filesize, created, data from web_bijlagen" );

            string sql = sb.ToString( );
            d.WriteLine( sql);

            NpgsqlDataAdapter   da  = new NpgsqlDataAdapter( sql, connection);
            da.Fill( ds);
            dt = ds.Tables[ 0];

            string  filename = string.Empty;
            int     fileSize = 0;
            byte[]  bytes   = null;

            foreach( DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                filename    = System.Convert.ToString   ( dr[ "filename"]);
                fileSize    = System.Convert.ToInt32    ( dr[ "filesize"]);
                bytes       = dr[ "data"] as byte[];
                WriteBijlage( filename, bytes);
            }

            DataDumper.Dump( dt);
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch( System.Exception ex)
        {
            d.WriteLine( ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if( connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) 
            {
                connection.Close( );
            }               
        }
    }

    private void WriteBijlage( string filename, byte[] bytes)
    {
        filename = string.Format( @"d:\Usr\Stephan\Junk\wBijlagen\{0}", filename);
        FileStream      fs  = new FileStream    ( filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);     
        BinaryWriter    bw  = new BinaryWriter  ( new BufferedStream(fs));
        bw.Write( bytes);   
        bw.Flush();

        fs.Close();
        bw.Close(); 
    }
```

Comment: Let me simplify my question, I have code to store and retrieve binary files in a postgress database and it is working fine if I run it inside a console program. If I run exact the same code in a Webapplication, the binary data gets corrupted, it is about twice as big. I think it should be something with encoding or so, but what ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

At the point where you return the bytes to you web app - first encode it as base64.  The code below works for the exact purpose in my one app.

```
thumbnail_url = @"data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Almost forgot to mention - you then use the return value as the src of your image.  Change type as you need to - mine was png.

I hope this helps.